# How large of a Kettle to brew 5 gallon and 10 gallon batches? (All Grain)

Tags: all-grain, kettle

If I want to brew a 5 gallon batch, how large of a kettle do I need to do so comfortably?

How about 10 gallons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my own experience, an 8 gal. kettle will barely work for a 5 gal. batch.  Even at that, you might have to boil a concentrated wort and add top up water after the boil.  Remember that in addition to accounting for trub and evaporation, you also need some headroom in there to start with.  I wouldn't recommend anything less than 15 gal. for a 10 gal. batch.

Comment: Thanks Denny. How about a 10 gal. for a 5 gal. batch?

Comment: That will work.  I remember the first time I did a 5 gal. batch in a 15 gal. kettle.  I thought there was no chance of boilover, then I turned my back for a second....the point being that no matter what size you use, you need to learn it's capabilities.

Comment: I use a 15 gallon kettle and typically do 10 gallon batches. However, I don't have any problems doing the occasional 5 gallon batch with that equipment.

Comment: Agreed - 8gk for 5gb is hard for pils/long boils. I have had a couple of brews with an 8 gal that I had to hold some of the wort out for 30 mins (2 hour boil)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on the losses you assume along the way.

For 5 gallons, if you assume a trub loss of 0.5 gallons, and evaporation loss of 1.0 gallon, then you would need 6.5 gallons of wort to get 5 gallons into a fermenter. If you follow the oft-quoted rule of thumb that you want minimum headspace in your kettle equal to one-third of your boil volume, that means the minimum kettle size is around 8-2/3 gallons. I have heard of people using 8-gallon kettles. I recommend more like 10-gallons.

For 10 gallons, I suppose you could double that.

Comment: Based on your assumptions, it sounds like there would be no headroom in the kettle.

Comment: @Denny, well to be clear, I am recommending 10-gal. kettle for a 5-gal. batch, and saying 8-2/3 is sort of a bare minimum for that size batch. I think we are in agreement as to the best practice.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I misunderstood.